# Invalid use of type class after forward declaration

Tags: c++, class, oop

I have written this program to demonstrate Double dispatch in C++. But it shows Invalid use of type class even though i have forward declared my classes. Is there any way to rectify this without writing in separate header files.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Number;       
class Integer;
class Rational;

class Number{
    public:
        int num, den;
        virtual void add(Number&) = 0;
        virtual void addInteger(Integer&) = 0;
        virtual void addRational(Rational&) = 0;
        virtual string toString() = 0;
};



class Rational : public Number{
        void addInteger(Integer& i){
            this->num = this->num + i.num*this->den;
            this->den = this->den;
            cout << this->num << "/" << this->den;
        }

        void addRational(Rational &r){
            this->num = this->num*r.den + this->den*r.num;
            this->den = this->den*r.den;
            cout << this->num << "/" << this->den; 
        }

    public:
        void add(Number& n){
            n.addRational(*this);
        }

        Rational(int n, int d){
            this->num = n;
            this->den = d;
        }
};


class Integer : public Number{
        void addInteger(Integer& i){
                this->num += i.num;
                this->den = 1;
                cout << this->num;
        }

        void addRational(Rational& r){
            this->num = this->num*r.den + r.num;
            this->den = r.den;
            cout << "this->num" << "/" << this->den;
        }

    public:

        void add(Number& n){
            n.addInteger(*this);
        }

        Integer(int n){
            this->num = n;
            this->den = 1;
        }
};



int main(){
    cout << "Helo World";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to separate your function declarations from their definitions. The function definitions need to appear after the class definitions they use.

#### Example Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Number;       
class Integer;
class Rational;

class Number
{
public:
    int num, den;
    virtual void add(Number&) = 0;
    virtual void addInteger(Integer&) = 0;
    virtual void addRational(Rational&) = 0;
    virtual string toString() = 0;
};

class Rational : public Number
{
    void addInteger(Integer& i);

    void addRational(Rational &r);

public:
    void add(Number& n)
    {
        n.addRational(*this);
    }

    Rational(int n, int d)
    {
        this->num = n;
        this->den = d;
    }
};

class Integer : public Number
{
    void addInteger(Integer& i);

    void addRational(Rational& r);

public:
    void add(Number& n)
    {
        n.addInteger(*this);
    }

    Integer(int n)
    {
        this->num = n;
        this->den = 1;
    }
};

void Rational::addInteger(Integer& i)
{
    this->num = this->num + i.num*this->den;
    this->den = this->den;
    cout << this->num << "/" << this->den;
}

void Rational::addRational(Rational &r)
{
    this->num = this->num*r.den + this->den*r.num;
    this->den = this->den*r.den;
    cout << this->num << "/" << this->den; 
}

void Integer::addInteger(Integer& i)
{
    this->num += i.num;
    this->den = 1;
    cout << this->num;
}

void Integer::addRational(Rational& r)
{
    this->num = this->num*r.den + r.num;
    this->den = r.den;
    cout << "this->num" << "/" << this->den;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Helo World";
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/Mb974d)

Comment: thank you this works fine. Now i want to create an object of class Number. whenever I try to define a constructor for it, it throws an error. What do I do?

Comment: @user2772093 If this solves your problem then you should **accept** the answer. Regarding your follow up question, if the issue is with a constructor that uses an object instance for a class before the definition of that class then the solution is exactly the same as it was with the function. Separate the constructor's declaration from it's definition. If this isn't clear then ask a new question for more help.